# Typo3 8.7.x / Typoscript: Get page uid of the TEXT which was found

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-8.x

How can I get the uid of the found TEXT?

```
test = TEXT
test {
    data = levelfield:-1, tx_myext_myfield, slide
    required = 1
    wrap = |
}
```

There are additional fields tx_myext_myfield2, tx_myext_myfield3,.. which I want to use, but I don't know how to get them with slide functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the levelfield feature you have to add these fields to the so called "rootline fields" using

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields']
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/singlehtml/Index.html#levelfield

Since you are getting just the value of a single field here, you can not access the other values though. If you want to access these values, you will need to fetch a whole record instead, which could be done using the cObjects

```
CONTENT
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html

or

```
RECORDS
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried that with CONTENT and slide, but I've got no results :( . https://pastebin.com/TnbTwD0B